# get values from other cell from other sheet if match value match with other cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have data on my sheet. Now I want to get data from my sheet1 to sheet2 if sheet1 Column A value match with sheet2 column A I want to copy Column B in sheet 2.

```
Sheet one

Column A |             | Column B
=================================
Hello    |             | 1
World!   |             | 2
Foo      |             | 3
Bar      |             | 4
```

What I have now

```
Sheet two

    Column A |             | Column B
    =================================
    Hello    |             |  
    World!   |             |  
    Bar      |             |
```

What I want

```
 Sheet two

    Column A |             | Column B
    =================================
    Hello    |             | 1
    World!   |             | 2
    Bar      |             | 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A:A; Sheet1!A:B; 2; 0)))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help . I got this error "Error
Result was not expanded automatically, please insert more rows (1)."

Comment: Here is how I try " =ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(L:L, sheet1!K:N, 14, 0)))"  Sheet 2 Data in L column and same data on sheet 1 in Coulmn K and I want to get N column Data is their any mistake that I made ?

Comment: Thanks again for your time , still got error this time 
"Error
VLOOKUP evaluates to an out-of-bounds range."

Comment: column N is 4th column from range K:N thats why you need: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(L2:L, sheet1!K:N, 4, 0)))`